Music War with Insects?
Looking for the name of an animated movie that I saw when I was a child.  It involves the main character fighting large, insect-like enemies using music.  The main character was a "child" but may not have been human - perhaps even a musical note or something similar?  I don't remember if the enemies were actually insects, or if they were conglomerations of something else that resembled a segmented insect body.
I'm fuzzy on the reason for the war, but I think that the main character was pulled into a different world in order to fight the enemies and then returned home after he was victorious.  He almost loses in the middle of the battle, but finds some renewed strength or new weapon that lets him defeat the invading forces.
The art style and music style are similar to the more abstract portions of the original Fantasia - I'm almost certain the music was classical.  I don't know if there was any dialogue, or if the whole story was told through music.  Despite the battling, the whole thing was very non-violent - the enemies didn't explode, they just sort of fell apart.  Definitely aimed toward children.
It is not Fantasia or Silly Symphony: Music Land.
Cartoon, color, feature length, saw it in the early 90's

What instruments (if any) are played in this battle?

I don't remember if the instruments are actually used as weapons (a la Music Land) or if music just accompanies the use of the weapons.  The projectiles may have been quarter notes and/or eighth notes.

I forgot to ask: Was it from the 90s or older than that? And was it short or feature length?

It was feature length, but not necessarily two hours long.  I was only 3 or 4 when I saw it, so I don't know when it was made, but I'm inclined to say it wasn't much older than the 80s or 90s.

could it have been 'Bumble Boogie'..?



A segment of the Disney feature Melody Time, pretty much in the Fantasia mold. 
Synopsis from the Disney Wiki: 

A surrealistic nightmare for a solitary, tiny, aghast, fast and desparate bumblebee (to a boogie-woogie version of Flight of the Bumblebee) trying to escape the visual display and imminent harmony of a musical frenzy. He is being attacked by flowers and butterflies made of piano keys, flowers made of trumpets (plus fireworks from repeated animation), snakes made of piano keys, the piano hammers hitting the "strings" of the sheet music, running piano keys diving on water and falling piano keys.


Welcome! Could you post a little info about how you think this is similar to the movie that the OP has described?

Great! Remember to quote (and link to) sources when you use them to avoid plagiarism issues.  I've also slightly reformatted it for you.

That's not the one I'm remembering, sorry.  But it was a fun watch!
